# How to connect an instance of a view to a model object? Ember.js

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

I have an arraycontroller associated with a model.  In my template I iterate over the elements in a handlebars template:

```
<ul>
 {{#each controller}}
   {{view Emb.ListView}}
 {{/each}}
</ul>
```

How do I access the model data of the current element in the view?

```
Emb.ListView = Em.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(**model data**),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working was:

```
<ul>
   {{#each controller}}
    {{#view Emb.ListView contentBinding='this'}}
      {{image}}
    {{/view}}
   {{/each}}
</ul>


Emb.ListView = Em.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  name: null,
  click: function(){
    console.log(this.get('content.attributes.image'));
  }
});
```